# Magento 2.3 - Getting error while sending mail n localhost

Tags: error, send-mail

I have used the correct email id and password. Also, on the less secure option in there.

> error: true message: "5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn
>   more at ↵ 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
>   s1sm36837704pgv.87 - gsmtp ↵"

I have added configuration as below ;
[image]

I have used below link to set up send mail functionality https://www.magepal.com/help/docs/smtp-magento/?utm_source=smtp&utm_medium=github#installation

Comment: Have you enabled less secure app in gmail account??

Comment: yes its enabled

Comment: can you plz share the config screenshot so i can check once

Comment: okay. but now its showing error as ` Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json.php:26 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\CacheManager.php(80)`

Comment: its something different, need more info.

Comment: @BirenPatel I have edited my question with adding SS of configuration. pls check and help to fix it

Comment: use SSL instead TSL

Comment: Smtp port 465 ....

Comment: also plz blur your email address in SS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103504/discussion-between-rk7002-and-biren-patel).

Comment: @BirenPatel  Thanks for your support.